# python-dateutil - RRule - Different times for different weekdays

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-dateutil, rrule

I'm using rrule as shown here:
https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57

I'm wondering if it somehow possible to create a rule where different times are specified for different weekdays
e.g. WEEKLY Thursday 6pm and Saturday 10am

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single rrule can not specify both pairs of days and hours, but you could use a [`rrule.ruleset`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-f83f4f0dd5fa533e0260bdcdd08df927594c32d2) to combine rrules:

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.rrule as RR
today = DT.date.today()

aset = RR.rruleset()
aset.rrule(RR.rrule(RR.WEEKLY, byweekday=RR.TH, byhour=18, count=3, dtstart=today))
aset.rrule(RR.rrule(RR.WEEKLY, byweekday=RR.SA, byhour=10, count=3, dtstart=today))
for date in aset:
    print(date)
```

yields

```
2015-03-26 18:00:00
2015-03-28 10:00:00
2015-04-02 18:00:00
2015-04-04 10:00:00
2015-04-09 18:00:00
2015-04-11 10:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems perfect! I'll try it out and then tick your answer :)